# How to stop my program during it is running?

Tags: vb.net-2010

I want to stop my program during it is running.
I have Form1 and Button1 in Windows form application.
Following code doesn't work because I am not able to click Button1 when my program is running...

My program is designed work with Excel. I mean I am doing some actions in excel via VB.NET.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Environment.Exit(0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fork out a thread for your computation.

Also note that if you want just to cancel that computation task instead of exiting your application entirely, you may use Cancellation token.

This example should give you some idea: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2